# Systemctl cannot start service after TasksMax is set

Tags: startup, performance, systemd, snap, services

I have a very small cloud instance of Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS.

Running `htop` shows 11 processes of `/usr/lib/snapd/snapd` running taking up tons of RAM...

```
1212 root       20   0  438M 11820  4636 S  0.0  2.4  0:04.78 ├─ /usr/lib/snapd/snapd
 1473 root       20   0  438M 11820  4636 S  0.0  2.4  0:00.79 │  ├─ /usr/lib/snapd/snapd 
 1462 root       20   0  438M 11820  4636 S  0.0  2.4  0:00.55 │  ├─ /usr/lib/snapd/snapd 
 1430 root       20   0  438M 11820  4636 S  0.0  2.4  0:00.49 │  ├─ /usr/lib/snapd/snapd 
 1429 root       20   0  438M 11820  4636 S  0.0  2.4  0:00.92 │  ├─ /usr/lib/snapd/snapd 
 1425 root       20   0  438M 11820  4636 S  0.0  2.4  0:00.59 │  ├─ /usr/lib/snapd/snapd 
 1419 root       20   0  438M 11820  4636 S  0.0  2.4  0:00.60 │  ├─ /usr/lib/snapd/snapd
 1413 root       20   0  438M 11820  4636 S  0.0  2.4  0:00.11 │  ├─ /usr/lib/snapd/snapd 
 1411 root       20   0  438M 11820  4636 S  0.0  2.4  0:00.00 │  ├─ /usr/lib/snapd/snapd 
 1410 root       20   0  438M 11820  4636 S  0.0  2.4  0:00.00 │  ├─ /usr/lib/snapd/snapd 
 1409 root       20   0  438M 11820  4636 S  0.0  2.4  0:00.40 │  └─ /usr/lib/snapd/snapd
```

I tried to limit the number of processes with the following: `sudo systemctl edit --full snapd.service`

Then under `[Service]` add:

```
TasksAccounting=true
TasksMax=4
```

After restart of the service, it fails to start with:
`systemd[1]: snapd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT`

Google fails to find any examples of actually setting up `TasksMax` outside of the man pages reference. The issue is not isolated to `snapd.service` btw.